# Flex row out of window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I made 2 column row with flex.
left column is list of items without shrink.
right column is chart with width to end window.
I try for chart width 100% basic 100% nothing helping, chart out of windows and add scroll.

```
<div class="frow">
        <div class="list">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="1"/>
                <label for="jack">item 1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chart" ref="chartDiv"></div>
</div>

.frow{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.list{
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.chart {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

If i try create without flex with display: inline-block for columns and chart width 100% all work without problem

Comment: Try to set a fixed width in your frow element

Comment: i dont know width , only know right column should to end of your monitor

Comment: flex-grow:1 instead of width:100%

Comment: add flex-grow:1 to .chart and remove width , dont help nothing change

Comment: min-width:0 to chart then ,

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `max-width:100vw;` and `flex:1;` on chart;

```
.frow{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width:100vw;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.list{
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.chart {
    height: 500px;
    flex:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.frow{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.list{
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.chart {
    height: 500px;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Add a `flex-basis:100%;` to your `.chart` and remove `max-width:100%` from `.chart`